# Who runs "Community♦" on the review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review, suggested-edits, community-user

Take a look at [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1483724). There were two "Approve" marks, but then [*Community*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) rejected it, and that was it. The suggestion was rejected with a *1-2* reject-approve ratio.

From *Community*'s [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), it states that "[it is] not really a person," and is actually "a background process" that does the following:

- Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
- Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
- Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
- Own suggested edits from anonymous users

None of those mention that it works the review queue. In addition, the right side of the [review overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) states that "Stack Overflow is moderated by [[**us**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)]" - ***NOT*** an automated bot.

If the automated bot can do review on its own, why would we be reviewing manually?

---

So, all together, I have a few small questions:

1. Is the ability to make an decision on behalf of everyone moderator-only or Community-only?
2. Why is a computer allowed to make decisions for us?
3. Why does *Community*'s [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) not mention that it can do that?
4. Is *Community* really *only* software, or is there some interaction behind the scenes?

Comment: MASTER BLASTER RUN - oh, wait, no.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Community rejects suggested edits when there has been a conflicting edit, or someone chose the "Reject and Edit" option.

In this case, the most recent fully-privileged edit by didierc won over the suggested edit. He or she probably had opened the editor before the suggested edit was submitted, and when didierc submitted his or her edit, the suggested edit was automatically rejected. Such automatic rejections are always attributed to Community.

This cannot happen if someone attempts to open the editor after the suggested edit is submitted; they will be redirected to the review task if they have 2k+ reputation, or the link will be disabled for others.

Community does not, by itself, review suggested edits and decide to approve or reject them. Also, if this type of rejection happens, it will not count towards an edit ban.

Comment: Conflicting edit?

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Two people editing and submitting edits at the same time. One submits first, but the other doesn't see those changes. Conflict ensues when the second tries to submit changes to a stale revision.

Comment: Specific note: the usual rules of "more substantial" do not apply here. A real edit conflicting with a suggested edit will *always* prevail.