# Community ♦ is a review monkey too?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, review, community-user

[This review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649254) was recently reviewed by the Community ♦ user and accepted. I thought this edit may have been a honey-pot but it wasn't.

I think Community needs a bit of time in the naughty corner.... if it wasn't for the user [strah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852866/strah) [correcting it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8158864/3) then we would have one ugly looking question on our hands.

Should the Community ♦ user be making decisions like this? Can it be improved?

[image]

Comment: @Kevin: So there is no bug? I find it strange that there was no record of Strah improving the suggested edit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because he improved from outside the review queue it's the correct behavior, improving from within the queue would have given him "review credit" as expected.

Comment: Right, so be came to the edit via the `edit (1)` link then; that's the detail I was missing here! :-)

Comment: There is a record (2nd Revision in this page) [Revision History](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8158864/revisions)

Answer (score 14):

Strah [choose to improve the suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170175/community-is-a-review-monkey-too/170176#comment503165_170176) but left the 'helpful' checkbox checked. I'll be charitable and suggest that that was accidental. However, he did so *outside* of the review queue, using the `edit (1)` link directly on the question itself instead.

Community is attributed 'helpful' accepts (example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649662), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649613)), just as it is attributed ['not helpful' *rejections*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166836/who-runs-community-on-the-review-queue/166837#166837). This is not always the case, like [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649218) for example, was also improved by Strah, and it is simply marked as approved. Community was not involved there; I think because the post was edited by a 3rd party between suggestion and review action there.

But take a look at the timestamps. Community 'accepted' the suggested edit at 09:34:49, and [strah's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8158864/revisions) was at 09:34:49. Ergo, Community accepted the suggested edit because Strah improved it and left the checkbox marked.

*Normally*, when done through the review queue, such improvements *also* are recorded as a review action; 'Edit' in this case. But because the edit was made outside of the queue, the only record of this is the approval attributed to Community, and the 'improved' edit by Strah in the post revision history.

Comment: Would that not show up in the suggested edit history as an improve event?

Comment: @Bart: The timestamps match exactly with the accept.

Comment: Yeah, it was my first idea as well, but I seem to remember that it would actually show up in the history as such...let's see if I can find one of mine...

Comment: For example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1631713) where I edited and, from what I recall, marked it as not helpful. It states "Edit" as my action...still, I think you're right.

Comment: @Bart: There is something interesting going on here, possibly a bug, actually. There is no record of strah reviewing it indeed, not on the suggested edit, nor on in the [review history](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history?page=4) (link to history page is very localized).

Comment: If the above is the case, it looks like a weird bug since it is not showing strah's edit in [review page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649254). Ideally it should have shown as ***strah reviewed ... : Edit***

Comment: @ACB: Exactly. I think this is actually a bug in the recording of the suggested edit.

Comment: An example of [approved edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649527)

Comment: @hims056: I just added such a reference for Strah to my answer. This is a curious case indeed.

Comment: @hims056: But I found counter examples as well; community approving suggested edits after an improve action.

Comment: @Bart: I found some examples of Community approving edits where a reviewer choose 'improve' then left the checkbox checked. Still, curious case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Time for the [Wheel of Blame](http://bit.ly/pYtBLT) I'd say.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is right. I have edited (I've chosen `Improve` option) the suggested edit and left the checkbox `edit was helpful` untouched (ticked by default). Strangely, this doesn't show in my `reviews` history.

Comment: @strah: Thanks for the confirmation! The plot thickens. :-)

Comment: @hims056: Note that in your case, Community approved the edit. :-)

Comment: @Strah: but it wasn't a review, now, was it? :-)