# Give Community ♦ a review ban

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, community-user

### Terrible review record

One of our moderators ([Community ♦](/users/-1/community)) has been approving terrible edits all over the place; for example, [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3463240), in which random words were `code formatted`. Clearly as a moderator this isn't what we expected from Community, and we should re-evaluate the faith we've put in them!

### People believe it's a real moderator

Obviously I know that Community ♦ isn't a real moderator and is a bot that (amongst other things) approves edits when another user edits a suggested edit and marks the original suggested edit as helpful. However, it gives the impression in the edit history that a moderator approved the edit. For example [here a user honestly believed Community ♦ was a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209305/user-making-inappropriate-edits-with-backticks?noredirect=1#comment669579_209305) and so didn't undo some terrible edits, thinking they were "sacrosanct because Community diamond OK'd them".

### Proposal

To avoid this confusion I suggest that the suggested edit screen shows the approval as being by the person who actually approved it (by editing). Making clear that it's a different kind of approve by calling it "Approve by edit".

So change

> [image: Approved 20 hours ago (GregS reviewed this 20 hours ago: Edit; Community ♦ reviewed this 20 hours ago: Approve)]

to

> [image: Approved 20 hours ago (GregS reviewed this 20 hours ago: Approve by edit)]

Comment: I say SNATCH away the *Diamond symbol* from this Community bot. It is spoiling the name of our dear (Diamond) moderators :P

Comment: MAybe give him a different suit? Say, a spade?

Comment: No, hearts work best! ♥

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - And then it'll use that heart to give us [such](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3463240) *Heart-Attacks*! ;)

Comment: I'm voting for ☠ (Skull and Crossbones, `U+2620`).

Comment: Glad to see this. If diamond is a bot, a moderator, and someone who works for the Organisation, it is can be confusing (well, 'tis to me). How about making the "helpful" flag more prominent and a "must do something to" or at least reconsider the default.

Comment: You've got a very valid point in there. I have seen lots of approved suggestions by the Community bot which were invalid accepts.

Comment: IMO using `Community` in that place is the main issue. It should display something from which you can infer that it was approved by editing.

Comment: @slugster related certainly, but not a dupe per sey (unless you take my request for a review ban seriously). I'm not totally sure what that question is asking. Also, it is marked "status-bydesign" whereas this is a feature request

Comment: Is it even an Approval? Am I confused by the terminology? A 2k user Edits the post. The original Suggestion is no longer relevant. 2k Edits don't need review. 2k Edit stands, with an "Assist" to the Sugestioner (or not, if the default Helpful is removed by the Editer). Is that the theory? In practice (I've seen it) some rubbish may be left behind by the Editor (deliberately spelled differently), but it has not been Approved by anyone, even the Community diamond.

Comment: @BillWoodger These are when a 2K user: sees the suggested edit, and then edits **from there**, so they have used the suggested edit as part of their edit. It is equivalent to approving the edit then immediately re-editing to add more. Where 2 edits clash the suggested edit is just rejected automatically

Comment: Fair enough, as you're asking for a specific improvement. I've changed my comment to "related". It's largely about the same thing as yours, but requesting a general improvement.

Comment: Related: [Community ♦ is a review monkey too?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170175/146015)

Comment: Is it an `Approval`? Can Approval sometimes be just one approver and still be an `Approval`? Other times requires three? To me it is what made it look like Community diamond had the magic.

Comment: @BillWoodger The 3 reviewers is a defence against robo reviewers who review too quickly, the theory is that if someone takes the time to edit a post then they'll take their time to review properly. Usually it works out, [sometimes it doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3463240). You're right though, as it stands the whole thing is quite confused

Comment: Community is the best guy on earth. So sweet.

Comment: I want to see what happens if community really were banned. Best not though I guess :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: ...or maybe even [U+1F4A9](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?page=1F&subpage=4&glyph=1F4A9).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, nah, that's outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. I'm actually surprised to have a font on this machine able to render it :)

Comment: But, but, but... [Community is a real person](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1) ;)

Answer (score 21):

To have edits "approved" or "denied" by community according to one of several criteria (only one approval and a timeout has expired) for instance seems like a bit of a hack, and it seems like in the majority of these cases a special case could be implemented in the view which explains what actually happened in the event of a community bot action.

There was also a feature request to add even more clarity by removing community's diamond as many comments on the question say ought to be done, back in 2013, which met with crushing defeat:

[Take the diamond away from Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214301/197190)

However, I am totally in favour of it.

Symbolizing network employees is another matter entirely, and if it's important to anyone to differentiate, perhaps it should be addressed elsewhere.

Community (and system daemons in general in the event that there are others) should perhaps have a hollow lozenge ◊ `U+25CA`.  It is indeed rather misleading at first blush and the purpose of these symbols is presumably to increase clarity.