# Is there something wrong with 'Community'?

Tags: support, spam, community-user

I was reviewing some edits when I came across this edit by `Community` (you know, this 1 reputation moderator NPC acccount). It seems to be spam:

[image]

P.S.: I tagged this 'support' because I didn't think any of the mandatory tags were a good fit. Feel free to retag and remove this P.S.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. I was asking why Community (who is supposed to be a perfect user) is posting spam, not how reviewing works. @benisuǝqbackwards

Comment: It looks to be an audit @11684, so it's not Community posting it...

Comment: Somewhat related; [Give the Community User ♦ a review ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209349/give-the-community-user-a-review-ban). The Community User ♦ isn't a high powered moderator, it just owns all the behaviour that doesn't belong to anyone else; so it probably shouldn't be shown as a mod

Comment: Perhaps you're right. But, I couldn't do anything. As you can see, it says 'this item is not reviewable'. It'd be a lame test if it didn't allow me to answer. @benisuǝqbackwards

Comment: Can you provide a link to the review?

Comment: <del>Which review?</del>  @TheGrinch I provided a screenshot, I lost the URL. Oops.

Comment: Ehm, the suggested edit.  (I still think it's a review audit, though).

Comment: How did you get to that review? It is almost certainly an audit review; but shown after it has already been acted upon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Looks like some sort of race-condition bug to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3727235

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just clicked at the orange number at the top right of my screen to review a few suggested edits, then after about 4 legitimate suggested edits this came up.

Comment: @TheGrinch Looks like Mat found it. I have no idea how he did that.

Comment: @mat: Yeah, how did you do that?

Comment: @11684 Clicking the back button in the browser (or clicking on a link to the already-reviewed audit) will cause it to say "this item is not reviewable."

Comment: @TheGrinch: the audits are listed in the review history. Searching for "Jekyll" in there found that link

Comment: @TheGrinch Honestly, I did neither.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As hinted at in the comments, [the review you saw](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3727235) was an [audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work).

Suggested edit audits are machine-generated nonsense temporarily attributed to real users on the site. However, once the audit has been completed, [the author is set to Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170683/stop-using-real-accounts-in-suggested-edit-audits/170713#170713) to emphasize that it is fake and no actual human is to blame for actually writing that nonsense.

Comment: Thanks! But why did I see it in the regular review queue while it wasn't auditing me?

Comment: And why does it say "this item is not reviewable?"

Comment: And why does the linked suggested edit show it was an audit review passed by Pekka? Why was it shown to the OP *as well*?

Comment: That's a good question, @TheGrinch. Near as I can tell, 11684 clicked through to the actual question after viewing the audit, and then went back to review again - this *should* have loaded the audit from the cache and displayed it with a real user and the ability to approve / reject... But it didn't.

Comment: Review audits *can* be shown to multiple people, @Martijn. That usually only happens when someone skips one and it hangs around in the queue for someone else to find.

Comment: Should we retag this as a [tag:bug], then?

Comment: Only if you can reproduce it; i can't.