# Should the repcap still apply when a post has been deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

### Background

2 days ago <strike>(10/1/2014)</strike>(9/1/2014) I answered assorted questions and went over the [repcap(+215)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220332/richard-tingle?tab=reputation). After that [a question I answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215554/why-dont-i-see-a-link-to-the-original-question-when-viewing-a-closed-as-duplica/215559#215559) was deleted by Community♦ when the user was deleted (no huge objection there, the question was based on a bizarre misconception<sup>1</sup>).

### Specific problem

However, even after the question was deleted I appear to still be repcapped at 165, is that the way the system is supposed to behave?

My understanding is that rep is not supposed to require recalcs these days; regardless I have waited 2 days to see if the problem resolves itself. I cannot currently do a manual recalc as that option has been removed as part of an unrelated bug.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> This whole saying 'the community user is doing a good job' thing feels very unnatural, erm, [it does a terrible job of reviewing though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209349/give-the-community-user-a-review-ban)

Comment: I think this question is the result of a misconception that I answered on the 10th, whereas I actually answered on the 9th (but it was deleted on the 10th), once that is taken into account (as per psubsee2003 currently deleted [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215869/220332) everything makes sense. This was because I looked at the "posted 2 days ago" rather than the actual timestamp

Comment: Helpful feature request: [Separate and visually indicate reversed events from the day's reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **were** rep capped.

Since other users can't see your deleted post records, it makes it more obvious when we look at it:

[image]

You had 1 accepted answer, 120 rep from 12+ upvotes on your answers, and 81 rep from your 18+ upvotes and 1 downvote on your question, that comes to 216, which is consistent with the rep cap.  And the extra "1" came from that downvote you made on a specific answer.

The removed post is shown in your reputation feed on the day it was deleted (which was on 1/10/2014, but technically the rep was lost on the day it was earned originally (which was on the day the answer was posted, 1/9/2014).  If you were rep capped on 1/9, you would eventually get credit for the other upvotes.