# Give credit to the anonymous, sooner

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, community-user

When an anonymous user suggests an edit, please indicate so in the revision history, instead of saying it's a user named Community ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/100003/15)). That removes the need to wonder what the heck is this weirdly named Mod. In fact I only realised Community refers to anonymous users after clicking on that [**suggest** link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4163763).

Comment: You are talking about the edit *after it was applied*. The edit suggestion is already so indicated.

Comment: The Community user is given the blame for *anything* that requires a valid user id but doesn't in fact have a valid user. Accepted edits suggested by anonymous are no exception.

Comment: So, to summarize: The edit was *not* made by an anonymous user; the revision is correctly attributed to the Community User instead. The community, after all, applied the edit after accepting the suggestion.

Comment: The edit was suggested by an anonymous user, and I would rather see that reflected in the revision instead of Community. That way I would not need to learn the concept of Community. Feels like too much of an implementation detail is exposed that way.

Comment: The Community User is used throughout the system; improving a suggested edit and unchecking the 'helpful' box causes the original suggestion to be rejected by Community User. When an edit conflict takes place between a suggested edit and a 2k+ user, the suggested edit is rejected by CU. Etc. etc. This would have to go *way* deeper than just anonymous suggestions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What you just described are not anonymous actions, they're actions taken by the system itself.  You can differentiate actions taken without human involvement at all from those that are from *a very human* unregistered user.

Comment: I would suggest just expanding the list of things the Community user does on it's user page. That way, if you click the profile link of "Community", it'll tell you what might have happened.

Comment: Related: It's even worse when community♦ seems to be approving terrible edits; [Give the Community User ♦ a review ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209349/give-the-community-user-a-review-ban)

Comment: @Sumurai8: Did you look at the [Community User profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)? What the user does is *already* listed there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I seem to require a bit of sleep. I totally missed the entry "Own suggested edits from anonymous users".

Comment: @MartijnPieters Re: [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223235/give-credit-to-the-anonymous-sooner#comment727196_223235): For edits suggested by logged-in users, the post history shows the user who suggested the edit, not the user(s) who approved it. To be consistent, for edits suggested by anonymous users, it *should* show "an anonymous user", not "Community ♦". Admittedly, it's kind of a minor issue, but fixing it would still reduce some confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, it's inconsistent.

#### Edit suggested by a registered user:

- [On review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5217):

  [image: Screenshot]
- [In post history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/130342/9):

  [image: Screenshot]

#### Edit suggested by an anonymous user:

- [On review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4163763):

  [image: Screenshot]
- [In post history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/100003/15):

  [image: Screenshot]

I know it's a minor and low-priority issue, but just how much effort could it really take to make the post history display anonymous edit suggestions the same way as they're shown on the review page?