# Show a deleted user's name in plain text instead of the Community user when viewing a review

Tags: feature-request, review, display-names, deleted-accounts

This is a follow up to [How can the Community user review a Low Quality post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284134/242209)

When viewing a review where one of the viewers has deleted their account, that user's username should appear in plain text instead of linking to the Community user.

> [image: Reviews]

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223235/give-credit-to-the-anonymous-sooner

Comment: Thanks for the freehand circle @ShadowWizard.

Comment: Actually was fixing the typo, then was horrified when I figured there's no FHRC in the request... ;)