# Could moderators actually review-ban the Community user, and what would happen if they did?

Tags: support, community-user, review-suspension

I get that this question is a little narrow in scope, but just for the sake of humor, I'm wondering...

[This question's title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209349/give-community-a-review-ban) ("Give Community ♦ a review ban") made me ask: do moderators actually have this ability?

What would happen internally if a moderator tried to assign a review ban to Community?

Comment: and in extension, can a moderator give another moderator a review ban?

Comment: I think this is technically possible since it got a user account, fake or not fake. What will happen nobody can tell though. :-P

Comment: Only one way to find out!

Comment: @Bart I think I remember the SO mods trying this out.  They can ban themselves and later remove the ban.

Answer (score 1):

No, Community is special-cased to be unbannable: "don’t mess with the Community User!"

[image: User not eligible for review suspension: don’t mess with the Community User!]

Moderators are likewise unbannable:

[image: User not eligible for review suspension: user is a moderator]

(Users without a privilege that grants access to review queues also can't be banned, which might lead one to believe that Community wouldn't need to be special cased since it lacks reputation. However, Community [always has all privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/-1) despite only having 1 rep.)

Moderators *can* put Community in timed suspension though, which is a roundabout way to review ban it. It doesn't seem to have any effects.

[image: This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 7 days.]

Comment: The Community user doesn't actually exist as a user; those are all actions taken by the system and it just puts in a -1 if there's no actual user behind it.

Comment: @Sonic I'm pretty sure there is a user in the database with an ID of -1. It does put in -1 as an ID if there is no actual user, but there is a user with ID -1: Community. Community is *a lot* like a normal user. It has an actual account with an associated email of "team@stackoverflow.com", **but** with no authentication methods (and as such can't be logged into by a human). Also: moderators can edit Community's profile. Also also: usually in user history logs the IP for Community is the IP of the user that ultimately instigated the action, but when there is no such user it is a 10.x.x.x IP.

Comment: Community is listed as having all privileges because it is a diamond moderator. Any user with moderator access will have the same effect when viewing the privileges page for them. It has nothing to do with it being the Community user. But as an aside - a suspension or review ban does nothing because the actions assigned to the Community user are almost always manually created via separate code. They do not go through the usual "can user do this" checks in the system and the review ban would never even be looked at.