# Can we please avoid calling this staff / bot / mod identifying label a "badge"?

Tags: discussion, badges, information-display, terminology, user-labels

Recently, indicators have been added to make explicit the fact that some accounts have a special status. Unfortunately, the term "badge" has been used to describe this feature; but calling this a "badge" is problematic because the term is already used for "achievement unlocked" indicators and other such rewards in the reputation system.

For example, see [Please use the new Mod/Staff badge tech to identify Community as a bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369071/please-use-the-new-mod-staff-badge-tech-to-identify-community-as-a-bot)

Could we please introduce a separate term for this?
I'll propose "label"; but perhaps someone can come up with a better suggestion. The main thing I'm requesting here is to not dilute the terminology by overloading an existing and thus far well-defined term.

Once there is a consensus, there will be work to systematically make this distinction in the Stack Exchange UI and documentation, and perhaps review previous meta posts about this topic and consider changing them where it makes sense.

Comment: As always, I',m slightly divided on whether this is a [tag:bug], [tag:feature-request], or [tag:discussion]. I went all in because breaking the terminology _is_ a bug and it's happening.

Comment: The example is no longer a good example because I went ahead and changed it.

Comment: -1 there are hundreds of English words that have more than one meaning and usage. Employees in the US wear name badges not labels.

Comment: Why is that an argument for not using consistent terminology within the documentation around a system Stack Exchange has full control over?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The newly introduced labels are not worn and they don’t contain names; and Stack Exchange is used by an international user base. I don’t see your point at all.

Comment: Polysemy is what some programmers might call a common feature of the English language. There's nothing wrong in using what is perhaps the best known expression among American English speakers.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, this is a request for using consistent terminology in order to avoid confusion. Polysemy is fine in _informal_ language but this is not about controlling how you talk about this at the coffee table.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I am not American and I have no problem with the term "badge" I'm.just saying that it's common in English -and any international language for that matter-  for the same word to have different meanings and *usage*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Official name is actually a **Label**. From the announcement post [**New Staff and Mod Labels** on site metas and Meta Stack
Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367899)

**EDIT:**

tripleee found a previous post where it's also called an **Indicator** [Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” **indicator**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator calls it "indicator" and seems similarly "official" so I'm not sure this is quite settled.

Comment: @tripleee Good find, that post predates me joining...Someone will have to figure it out.

Comment: @tripleee in the comments there staff also use the term label, for example [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator#comment1083366_331661) by Yaakov.

Comment: Let's call it settled then (-:

Comment: We can go with label, as we already have other things on the site called badges. Though please forgive the occassional slip-up (the css class in Stacks for these is `s-badge`).

Comment: Hmmm someone needs to swing that not so giant S around, and make that badge into a label, @YaakovEllis

Comment: I notice there is now a tag [tag:user-labels] so that basically confirms the official status. (Thanks!)

Comment: @tripleee not really, I'm the one who created the tag, so this specific thing doesn't mean it's official. However, as staff didn't say otherwise, pretty sure we can keep using "label".

Comment: @Luuklag Well, the same [class](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/badges/) is also used for badges, and reputation notifications, and bounties, and some other stuff. It's an all-in-one class that covers a great many use cases, and doesn't make sense to use a bunch of different class names to do mostly the same thing. We just have to remember to call it something else when talking about it in posts.