# Please give Community its diamond back

Tags: feature-request, community-user, user-labels

Recently a long standing request has been [fulfilled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369071/please-use-the-new-mod-staff-label-tech-to-identify-community-as-a-bot), identifying the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) as a bot.

[image: Screenshot of the profile of the Community user, showing it's new "Bot" label. A small light gray rectangle with the word Bot in it.]

I'm highly in favour of this change, especially with regards to the new stream of comments posted by it from the review queue's. This change however did make it less obvious that this bot performs several moderating activities, like deleting spam posts, deleting abandoned questions etc.

#### Can Community please get their diamond back to make it obvious they have moderating capabilities as well?

Comment: It's a badge, no it's a label. It's a mod, no it's a bot. There's a diamond, no we want a tag/label/badge. Whatever will be next? Community has a blue avatar, can we make it orange? A moderator strongly suggests there is a human being, does it not?

Comment: @Mari-LouA they are called label, no need to confuse about that. Including a diamond would be rather trivial, as it is a simple character. I don't ask to include the "moderator" word, just the diamond.

Comment: @Luuklag, but the diamond is part of the label now, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, but it wouldn't be too hard to include a diamond in the bot label

Comment: I don't think the difficulty of adding it is really the issue. Are there bots that will be labelled that wouldn't get the diamond? The purpose of the label is not to explain all the things the bot can be used to do, it's to distinguish it from a human. Adding a diamond doesn't add any useful information right now. Maybe in the future if there is a bot account that has a different level of access and we would need to distinguish it from the community bot, we could add a diamond to Community.

Comment: Especially in regards to the new stream of comments posted by it from the review queue's I think the bot should not have a diamond. The posts are posted on behalf of normal users and I fear that it would confuse the recipients of such comments into thinking they come from a mod, which would give the comments much more creditability then they should have.

Comment: (but some cute bot icon instead of a diamond would be nice https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/user-robot?style=light :) )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Diamond implies an actual moderator, that handles flags, or can be reached when one is in trouble.

The Community account can do neither of those, the diamond was there just to distinguish it from ordinary accounts, when the only possible way was with the moderator label. Now that we have other labels, this original reasoning for giving the diamond to the Community user is moot.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, thanks for the change.

The answer is:

#### Big  NO

Why?

I agree with [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/237989/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz)'s comment.

A bot should not have a diamond, especially in light of the recent stream of comments it has been posting from the review queues. Sometimes it's spread a false message and the new user totally confuses between a moderator vs a bot.

Suggestion:

Again I agree with [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/237989/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz)'s comment. Instead of a diamond, a charming bot icon would be excellent. I am not a designer, so I am not able to post any icon, but I leave it for [Aaron Shekey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey) or any community volunteer suggestions are welcome.

Comment: User *samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz* made three comments (one of them seems to have been deleted). Which one are you referring to? Or all of them? You can link directly to a particular comment (the link is in the "1 hour ago" - example: [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's first comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369868/please-give-community-its-diamond-back#comment1234417_369868))

Comment: Suggestion for super cute bot icons: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/

Comment: ... or maybe the bot can indeed have the diamond back: https://i.stack.imgur.com/209Be.png