# User labels, such as the Community user's "Bot" label, are missing in the "Reviewer Stats" panel

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, community-user, user-labels

Since [Please use the new Mod/Staff label tech to identify Community as a bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369071/please-use-the-new-mod-staff-label-tech-to-identify-community-as-a-bot/369844#369844), I expected the Community user to always show a trailing "Bot" label.

When looking at old suggested edit review tasks, I noticed that Community isn't consistently a "Bot", but appears as any other user. All though a very active one by the look of the statistics:

[image: When pressing "Reviewers Stats" the Community user is shown without the trailing "Bot" label.]

The screen shot is from this [Stack Overflow suggested edit review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29825681)

I'm on Windows 10 using Opera version 79.0.4143.50. I noticed it and turned [all my scripts and styles off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuz8I.png). But it persists.

I'm assuming it's a bug, hence the tag. But I can't be completely sure, so: Is this intentional?

[Spevacus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/622284/spevacus) mentions in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370323/community-user-missing-a-bot-box#comment1235912_370323) that

> It looks like ALL suffix-icons (such as moderator diamonds) are missing from the "Reviewer stats" panel.

Attaching this screen shot for [this Meta Stack Exchange suggested edit review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79376):
[image: Screenshot of missing moderator labels.]

Comment: It looks like ALL user labels (such as moderator diamonds) are missing from the "Reviewer stats" panel. See: [this suggested edit review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79376) ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/rmdUpMj.png)) - You may want to edit that info into this bug report. For reference, I'm on Chrome ver. 93.0.4577.82