# The message "Community♦ reviewed this ...: Approve" in suggested edits

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, community-user, improve-edit

I've noticed that the message above appears sometimes when I choose "Improve" in the suggested edit review queue, as [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2690793).

Given that the Community approval and my edit have the same time stamp, I believe this is an automated process.

[In another example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2703772), the suggest edit had 3 approve votes (by real users) prior to my edit, so the Community notice did not appear.

Could someone please clarify what is going on?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166837/172958

Comment: ok, it's duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone reviews a suggested edit and makes their own edit (as long as they check "the suggested edit was helpful"), the original suggested edit is automatically approved by Community and the new edit is also made.

If, however, the reviewer makes their own edit but un-checks "the suggested edit was helpful box", the original edit is rejected by Community and the new edit is made.

Answer (score 0):

When you `Improve` a post, the suggested edit needs to be either approved or denied instantly; it can't stay open after your edit.  Since you don't technically have the ability to unilaterally approve/reject an edit, the community user does it on your behalf, since it's a moderator.